# Are applications using STL ought to be memory-leak prone when OS cannot allocate memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, stl

I personally am not fan of exception handling. As in many places it's suggested that **catching exceptions and still continuing with program execution is not recommended as good programming practice.**

However, since **STL containers throw exceptions** (viz. bad_alloc), there is no choice than having exception handling blocks in our code. But while dealing with STL calls in my application, I am finding its very tough to make application leak-proof and robust.

A sample code below demonstrate how STL (with exception  handling) might cause memory leaks:

```
void my_function()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> integers; // It can throw bad_alloc here (1)

        for (int i=0; i<10240; i++)
        {
            int* myintptr = new (std::nothrow) int;
            if (myintptr == NULL) // Memory not allocated. But no exception thrown so I am safe to continue.
                continue;
            *myintptr = i;
            integers.push_back (*myintptr ); // It can throw bad_alloc here (2)
            delete myintptr;
        }
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        // If it come here after throwing exception at (1) its fine. But if it has thrown exception at (2) then it just leaked memory allocated by new int
    }
}
```

*(Ofcourse this is just simplified version to demonstrate similar situations in big and complex code.)*

Now, there could be couple of suggestions here:

**1. Use exception handling on most narrowed block:** So it means I've to place another try..catch around call push_back. But then, if I want to place try...catch block around each STL calls, how my code would look like?

**2. Make sure you have enough memory:** It might also be suggested that we shouldn't land into situation where OS cannot allocate memory. So, we can proactively check if adequate memory is available before we proceed with STL calls.
But this strategy will not work always. Having enough free memory doesn't guarantee us that further requests to allocate memory would be succeeded (e.g. Say if memory is fragmented.
Additionally, if there are other heavy memory consuming applications running on the system, then OS might find its very hard to find space in physical memory for allocation, so it simply could deny the request.)

So at the end the big question is:

**How can we make our application using STL robust (no crash, keeps running even when OS denies memory allocation request) and full proof (no leakage even if there are exceptions)?**

Comment: Avoiding raw pointers is one way

Comment: How realistic a danger is `std::bad_alloc` anyway? And can you reasonably catch it at all? I treat it as something that doesn't happen in sane circumstances and terminates the whole application when it does happen.

Comment: You've already received the correct answer (RAII). I just wanted to add that even for your original, non-RAII or Java-like solution, a better practice would be to `catch(...)`. This is for two reasons: 1.) It is robust in the case that the code inside of the `try` block changes in the future. 2.) It illustrates that you are not interested in the exceptional situation itself but only in the context in which it happened.

Comment: btw, +1 for the question. It shows a complete misunderstanding of some basic C++ fundamentals but at the same time a great willingness to learn, which should be honoured IMO.

Comment: @delnan: As I like to say, this entirely depends on how important your software is, and how many crashes per year and user are OK. A tool written for one's one computer will likely be less important than e-banking server software :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl The situations where it's a good idea to catch OOM exceptions seem exceedingly rare. When it's super important that you don't crash, you don't want to run out of memory either so you don't do dynamic allocation at all. When it's super important and distributed, conventional wisdom is that it's better to crash and re-start, because failure is inevitable and correctly salvaging the node is hard and tricky to make 100% correct. There are probably cases where you want to recover, but they seem quite rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer scattered allover in previous answers. I am just posting it herewith consolidated. But all credit goes to those individual experts:

*By [Dietmar Kühl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120273/dietmar-kuhl):*

> You should learn about [RAII!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) The basic idea is that you never have any resource which isn't guarded by an object cleaning up the resource upon destruction. (try/catch blocks are certainly not useful to deal with resource clean-up and are mostly used to deal with the actual problem.)

*By [bobah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267482/bobah):*

> To STL memory allocation specifically - all containers (unless have implementation bugs) are RAII so won't cause memory leaks even when allocator thrown an exception.

*By [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau):*

> In your example, you can protect the new by using a std::auto_ptr (or std::unique_ptr in C++11). No need to delete the auto_ptr as it automatically destructs when goes out of scope. 
>   But you can call reset whenever you deliberately want to delete it.

```
void my_function()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> integers; // It can throw bad_alloc here (1)

        for (int i=0; i<10240; i++)
        {
            std::auto_ptr<int> myintptr(new (std::nothrow) int(i));
            if (myintptr.get() == NULL) // Memory not allocated. But no exception thrown so I am safe to continue.
                continue;
            integers.push_back (*(myintptr.get()) ); // It can throw bad_alloc here (2)

            myintptr.reset(); // You can call reset to delete smart pointer (Although no need to delete in this example)
        }
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        // If it come here after throwing exception at (1) or (2) its fine. No leaks
    }
}
```

*By [user2079303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079303/user2079303):*
It's also worth to note,

> you can use reserve (in case of vector) 
>   Because reserve guarantees the required space beforehand, there will be no reallocations when you push new elements and therefore no bad_alloc.

Answer (score 7):

You should learn about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)! The basic idea is that you never have any resource which isn't guarded by an object cleaning up the resource upon destruction. Since destructors of local variables are called whenever a block is left (unless using something like `longjmp()`) this approach entirely automates clean-up. The RAII technique was partly developed to deal with exception but even if none are thrown I find that this programming style reduces resource leaks dramatically.

BTW, the recommendations you highlighted about not continuing when there are exception is absolute nonsense! Also, except for a few locations where an operation can reasonably be restarted, you probably won't have any `try`/`catch` blocks! They are certainly not useful to deal with resource clean-up and are mostly used to deal with the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you can protect the `new` and remove the `delete` by using a `std::auto_ptr` (or `std::unique_ptr` in C++11):

```
void my_function()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> integers; // It can throw bad_alloc here (1)

        for (int i=0; i<10240; i++)
        {
            std::auto_ptr<int> myintptr(new (std::nothrow) int(i));
            if (myintptr.get() == NULL) // Memory not allocated. But no exception thrown so I am safe to continue.
                continue;
            integers.push_back (*(myintptr.get()) ); // It can throw bad_alloc here (2)
        }
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        // If it come here after throwing exception at (1) or (2) its fine. No leaks
    }
}
```

Of course, you could simply eliminate the unnecessary extra allocation altogether:

```
void my_function()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> integers; // It can throw bad_alloc here (1)

        for (int i=0; i<10240; i++)
            integers.push_back (i); // It can throw bad_alloc here (2)
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        // If it come here after throwing exception at (1) or (2) its fine. No leaks
    }
}
```

Which could then be simplified to this:

```
void my_function()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> integers(10240); // It can throw bad_alloc here (1)

        for (int i=0; i<10240; i++)
            integers[i] = i; // no allocation here, already allocated above
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        // If it come here after throwing exception at (1) its fine. No leak
    }
}
```

Comment: Can be further simplified (I think) with: `std::vector<int> v(10240); std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);`

Comment: Use of smart pointers, is perfect hint :) Thanks for the same. (The code was _only for demonstration_ of the problem. It could be bigger and complex code involving other containers also. So please lets not think of this code in literal sense)

Answer (score 1):

Correct (conservative) usage of exceptions dictates to discard the object that threw an exception out (or a set of associated objects which would mean that the program encapsulation is suboptimal) of it and catch exceptions only where the catcher can itself potentially survive. Memory allocation exceptions are just another type of exceptions (with one important feature - in most cases they tend to reoccur, so whether the applications should survive them is a question, not mission critical ones should probably just quickly die to let itself be restarted).

To STL memory allocation specifically - all containers (unless have implementation bugs) are RAII so won't cause memory leaks even when allocator thrown an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can avoid the potential leak using `std::vector::reserve`

```
std::vector<int> integers;
integers.reserve(10240); // may throw bad_alloc
for (int i=0; i<10240; i++)
// ...
```

Because `reserve` guarantees the required space beforehand, there will be no reallocations when you push new elements and therefore no `bad_alloc`.

Another way to avoid leaks is to not use `new` in the first place.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, could you please elaborate on how it isn't such a good thing, please.

Comment: Because of your second advice primarily. Additionally you'll need to know in advance hoe much memory needs to be reserved with the `vector`!